# Entity Framework Self Referencing Using Non-Primary Key Column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an employee table that self references to determine organization structure. I'm having some trouble trying to set this up using Code-First (POCO) fluently.

An employee record has both a **"Position"** field and a **"ReportsTo"** field and neither of the columns are the primary key (employee.id).

An employee with a "**ReportsTo**" value of "**08294**" , is an employee of a direct report of an employee with "**Position**" value of "**08294**".

Can anyone offer up some info on how to set this up using EF code first, fluently...is it possible?

I tried the code below and am getting error:

> Employee_Employees_Source_Employee_Employees_Target: : The types of
>   all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must
>   be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role.
>   The type of property 'ReportsTo' on entity 'Employee' does not match
>   the type of property 'Id' on entity 'Employee' in the referential
>   constraint 'Employee_Employees'.

**Employee.cs**

```
public class Employee
{
     public int Id  { get; set; } //pk 
     public string Position { get; set; } // i.e. 06895
     public string ReportsTo{ get; set; } // i.e. 08294         

     public virtual Employee Supervisor { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Employees)
                .WithOptional(e => e.Supervisor)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ReportsTo);
```

I think more than anything, I would like to keep the POCO free of EF "stuff" and be able to do something like:

```
employee.IsSupervisor(); // based on child employee count.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the relationship configuration. If you want to configure your one to many relation without using a FK, you could do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Employees)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Supervisor);
```

Now if you want to use a FK property, then add  this property to your model class:

```
public class Employee
{
  //...
  public int SupervisorId  { get; set; }
}
```

And map your relationship this way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Employees)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Supervisor)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.SupervisorId);
```

To resolve your issue related with `ReportTo` and `Position` properties,I think  you should handle that logic in your code. If you want to know if an `Employee` is a supervisor based on the count of `Employees` property, you could use a [NotMapped](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#NotMapped) property:

```
 public class Employee
{
  [NotMapped]
  public bool IsSupervisor
  {
     get
     {
         return Employess.Count>0
     }
  }
}
```

You can do the same using Fluent Api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Ignore(e => e.IsSupervisor);
```

PS: Remember initialize `Employees` in your class'constructor.

Comment: this is close, but I didn't want to create another key (supervisorId) as the reports to and position represent the needed structure. I was hoping I could avoid having to explicitly set the supervisor for each employee and persist it to the DB..with your example I have to set each `employee.Supervisor = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Position == employee.ReportsTo).FirstOrDefault()`. I may end up going this route, but do you know of another way?

Comment: I'm affraid that you have two options here, setting the `Supervisor` property as you show me in your comment, or if you know the `SupervisorId`, set that FK property and that's it.

Answer (score -1):

The error you get is because it is trying to map a PK of `int` type to a FK of `string` type. User `int` for all of your key fields.

Then, you need to declare your OnModelBuilding like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
.HasOptional(e => e.Supervisor)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(s => s.ReportsTo);
```

To get something like `IsSupervisor()` you can take advantage of partial classes. Create another class file which is a `public partial class Employee` (and modify your original one to be partial), then in your new file you will add a property that does whatever you want, and decorate it with `[NotMapped]` attribute. Yours will probably look something like `public bool IsSupervisor {get { return (Employees == null) ? false : true; } set {} }` The new partial class is where you can do whatever you want for the POCO without changing the EF class (make sure you use `[NotMapped]` though).